# How to synchronize update Facebook with Twitter *without* using the official Twitter application?

Tags: facebook, twitter

I want to update Facebook through my twitter - that is, whenever I post something on twitter, I want it on my FB wall.

However, the "default", official way does not work for me due to error described here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15361703/twitter-to-facebook

> What you are describing is a known bug Twitter bug.
>
> The problem comes up when your Twitter account was previously
>   connected to another Facebook account that you deleted/deactivated
>   without removing the Twitter app first.

which is true for my case.

The error I get is

> Facebook reported an error. The error has been reported to our
>   engineering team. Please try again as it might be a temporary problem.

However, if I search for some other app offering synchronization on Google, all I find are tutorials for this official way. So, my question is - is there another way that works too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started to use [Buffer](https://buffer.com/) application, and it works all right for me.

Answer (score 2):

[IFTTT](http://ifttt.com) has re-enabled their twitter triggers - you can use [this recipe](https://ifttt.com/recipes/112202) which will post all tweets tagged with #fb to facebook.

Comment: I am thinking of doing something else: on IFTTT do both Mail->Twitter and Mail->Facebook recipes.

Comment: https://zapier.com this let you "input" tweets, but I think that you can only post on Facebook pages; so you can combine zapier and IFTTT (twitter-->mail (for example) --> Facebook

Comment: For what it's worth, there are "new" Twitter triggers (re-)added to IFTTT just today. "New Tweet by you" is one of them.